# Ergodic and space-time differences

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology

I read [a resolution of St. Petersburg paradox](http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/statistical_physics_attacks_st_petersburg_paradox_resolved-96549), which says that the game is not ergodic. Yet, if you play n games in row, you average income will be the same as if you play n parallel games,

[image]

This means that the process is stationary and I can replace the time averages with ensemble averages, which is exactly what ergodicity means. Were am I wrong?

The fact that space and time averages are equal [is confirmed by Peters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox#Peters) and it [is further used at Hommock Physicist page as the confirmation of non-ergodicity](http://www.science20.com/comments/131500/Re_Statistical_Physics_Attacks_St_Petersburg_Paradox_Resolved). So, I do not understand why what I am sure is ergodicity is used as something converse.

PS [Wikipedia says that a process is ergodic when we can deduce its staistical properties from a single run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process). This is what spb researchers prove. How do they conclude that the spb process is not ergodic?